# Efficient transfer of planar images for rendering in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-management

What is the most efficient way to transfer planar YUVA images for rendering in OpenGL?

Currently I'm using 4 separate textures (Y, U, V, A) to which I upload to from 4 separate PBOs during each frame. However, it seems to be much more efficient to transfer a lot of data in few textures, e.g. transferring YUV422 to a single packed texture is ~50% faster than transferring the same data to 3 (Y, U, V) separate textures.

Some thoughts I've had on the matter is whether I could use 2 array textures, one for (Y, A) and one for (U, V), would that be faster?

Another alternative I've considered is to convert from planar to packed while copying data to the PBO for transfer, though this does have some CPU overhead.

Any suggestions?

NOTE: dim(Y) == dim(A) && dim(U) == dim(V) && dim(Y) != dim(U).

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering how you are generating the textures? ie generated dynamically or loaded in from a file?  If they are loaded from a file I would recommend loading the textures as a single rgba texture to load it and utilise a fragment shader to process it as yuva, the data can then be loaded in one go, and should yield substantially better results in performance.

If there is some more information on how the texture is being utilised I should be able to give you a more detailed answer.

EDIT:  The way that I normally handle YUVA is to render to a texture; use the GPU to convert the RGBA to YUVA then send the result back to the CPU via *glGetTexImage* for example and handle the resultant data as YUVA (or drop the alpha and use it as YUV).

In regards to the differently sized textures I wouldn't worry, pack the data as you see fit, and read it out as you see fit, you can have each channel have  0 values in all the areas where you don't have any valid data for example or use and off but memorable value (like your birthday and have values along the lines of 0.17122012 (today's date)) so you can easily programmatically ignore them, or make the channel handling code only read particular dimensions based on the channel its operating on, the extraneous data is minimal or if 0s its even less, and the speed gains of utilising a GPU to handle the data offset it and still leave a fast system in place.

Hope that helps a bit more.

Comment: The texture source data is generated dynamically on the fly by decoding a video stream.

Comment: Actually, several (as many as possible) video streams are decoded in parallel, which is why transfer performance is of import.

Comment: Loading multiple planes into a single multichannel texture is only possible if all the planes have the same resolution. YUV data however is usually subsampled in the chroma planes, i.e. use a different resolution. In that case multiple textures must be used.

Comment: these then being applied to a surface as a texture?

Comment: datenwolf is right, however, there are tricks that can be used to overcome this, such as packing the subsampled textures into one channel etc.  I am just wondering if you have looked at pre-made solutions as a source of inspiration?  For example http://www.yuvtoolkit.com/ helped me a lot to see what was going on when I was first taking a look at putting video textures onto opengl surfaces (I understand that might not be what you wish to do, however the code is well laid out and makes for interesting reading)  I am at work atm, but will answer far more in depth once I get home:)